# Restricting email notification for private site in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have added a script to send mail whenever a site is created. How to restrict the email notification if the site created is a private site. Here is my java script

```
var mail = actions.create("mail");

var node = people.getGroup("GROUP_EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS");

    if(node){
       var members = people.getMembers(node);         
    }
mail.parameters.from = "Administrator@community.com"
mail.parameters.subject=" A new site called " + document.properties.name+" is created"; 
mail.parameters.text="Click http://sameer_w7:8080/share/page/site/" +   document.properties.name + "/dashboard" + "   to join the site";

 for(var i=0;i<members.length;i++)
 {
  mail.parameters.to = members[i].properties.email;
 //execute action against a document
 mail.execute(document);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the **siteVisibility** state of a site.

Take a look at the [SiteService Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_Services_API#Site) page.

Something like this should work:

```
if (document.properties["st:siteVisibility"] != "PRIVATE"){
<your email action here>
}
```

Be sure you have selected type is **st:site** in your rule, otherwise add an extra check on that.

Comment: Thanks I didnt modify script but I modified the rule and st:site contains public and it is working